# AV1 encoding with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

[Since the newest version](https://www.ffmpeg.org/index.html#news) (4.0), ffmpeg supports the [AV1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AV1) codec. [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/press/aomedia.html) should also be able to play AV1 videos.

Unfortunately I haven't found the syntax to encode existing videos to AV1. I use ffmpeg from the command line like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.avi
```

But what are the required options for AV1?

Comment: You really *do not* want to use AVI containers anymore.

Comment: @DanielB the new one AV1 not AVI

Comment: Sure. However, in your question you have `.avi`.

Comment: That's the default sample of FFMPeg at https://www.ffmpeg.org

Comment: What is the best container to use for AV1?

Comment: @AaronFranke Based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AV1#Supported_container_formats and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats#Video_coding_formats_support , only `.mp4` that is "MPEG-4 Part 14" has specifically defined how to contain AV1 videos, but work is underway for WebM/MKV containers.

Comment: You seem to confuse `avi` and `av1`. `avi` is a container format, `av1` is a video codec.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek no i'm talking about codec in the question

Comment: I was refering to your first comment. There is no "new one" AV1 (the codec) as it as nothing to do with AVI, the container. And hence, if you look at second link I gave on Wikipedia you could see that AV1 (the codec) can not be used in an AVI (the container) file. If you look at ffmpeg documentation on their wiki about AV1 you will see they use either MKV or MP4 as container.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

AV1 decoding and encoding is provided via `libaom` if your ffmpeg build has the library linked. In order to link the library, compile ffmpeg with `--enable-libaom` (see the [compilation guides](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide)).

The basic syntax is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libaom-av1 -strict -2 output.avi
```

(Note: `-strict -2` or `-strict experimental` is required since the encoder is, at present, experimental. AV1 encoding is **very** slow at this point.)

You may specify a target bitrate (e.g., `-b:v 2M`) or a target quality level (e.g. `-crf 30`). `libaom` also supports 2-pass encoding.

For more info, see the [AV1 encoding guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AV1) on the FFmpeg Wiki.

Comment: thanks so far! Could you also add a reference or did you gat that by trying?

Comment: No ref yet; I'll add it to the documentation soon.

Comment: Simpler/Clearer in newer versions: `ffmpeg -c:v av1 -strict experimental`

Comment: This will pick the highest priority AV1 encoder available - there are three available, IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

The [FFmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AV1) mentions that there are now *three* software AV1 encoders in FFmpeg: `libaom`, SVT-AV1, and `rav1e`. It also claims that "[in] 2020, SVT-AV1 was adopted by AOMedia as the basis for the future development of AV1 as well as future codec efforts."

Gyan's answer already provides some information on libaom.

[SVT-AV1's upstream documentation](https://gitlab.com/AOMediaCodec/SVT-AV1/-/blob/master/Docs/Ffmpeg.md) contains several examples for using it within FFmpeg. For instance, if you want fast encoding, they offer this example command:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mkv -c:v libsvtav1 -preset 10 -crf 35 -c:a copy outfile.mkv
```

rav1e boldly claims to be the fastest AV1 encoder. Whether or not this is true in practice of course depends on the content being encoded. An example command lives in [the FFmpeg docs proper](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#librav1e):

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v librav1e -b:v 500K -rav1e-params speed=5:low_latency=true output.mp4
```

(Note that this sets the video bitrate to 500K, which is higher than the [default of 200K.](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Codec-Options))